# Appending to []interface{} problems --Additonal Info

Tags: go

To followup on my last question, I have tried again:

I create a collection of records (**map[string]string**)

When I append two different collections to an interface slice:  **var db []interface{}**

what I expected is     *db[0] collection1 and db[1] collection2*

What I get is         *db[0] collection2 and db[1] collection2*

**The following is the active code:**

```
record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWC", d, "Left", "---", "10", "12.5"))
record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWC", d, "Left", "---", "10", "12.5"))
fmt.Println("Record 1: ", record)
db = append(db, record)
fmt.Println("Database1 = ", db)

record = record[:0]
fmt.Println("Record: ", record)
record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWT", d, "Left", "---", "15", "12.5"))
record = append(record, newWorkDataItem("FWT", d, "Right", "---", "15", "12.5"))

fmt.Println("Record 2: ", record)
db = append(db, record)
fmt.Println("Database2 = ", db)
fmt.Println("db[0] ", db[0])
fmt.Println("db[1] ", db[1])
```

**The following is the Results:**

```
Record 1:  [map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWC Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWC Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5]]

Database1 =  [[map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWC Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWC Notes:--- Reps:10 Side:Left Weight:12.5]]]

Record:  []

Record 2:  [map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Right Weight:12.5]]

Database2 =  [[map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Right Weight:12.5]] [map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Right Weight:12.5]]]

db[0]  [map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Right Weight:12.5]]

db[1]  [map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Left Weight:12.5] map[Data:11 27 2019 Exercise:FWT Notes:--- Reps:15 Side:Right Weight:12.5]]
```

AS you can see by appending a new collection to 'db' seems to not only overwrite the first collection and then appends the new collection.

So we get collection2, collection2   NOT collection1, collection2

Comment: I recommend you read [this](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) to better understand how slices work. Here's also a bit of commentary to go with your code https://play.golang.com/p/J_vWRsCd5rN

Answer (score 1):

A slice is a view over an array. When you do:

```
record = record[:0]
```

You are not creating a new empty slice. You are still using the underlying array, with a new slice viewing it as a slice with a length of 0. As you append new elements to `record`, you are overwriting the underlying array elements.

Replace the above statement with:

```
record = make([]recordType,0)
```

or

```
record= []recordType{}
```

to use a new slice for records.

Comment: it's `make([]record, 0)` not `new(recordType,0)`.

Comment: The answer is when building a new collection: set "record = nil" this assures

Comment: the record is initialized by the new append statement. Now I get the desired db[0] collection1 and db[1] collection2.   THANKS EVERYONE FOR THE HELP